# Is this Fourier series calculation right?

Tags: fourier-series

I'm working on a course problem,

> Calculate the Fourier series of the periodic function $f(t)$ with fundamental period $T=4$ defined on $[-2,2)$ by $$f(t)=
> \begin{cases}1-|t|&-1\leq t\leq1 \\0&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

I get $$\text{even function}\implies\text{cosine series}\implies f(t)=\frac{1}{4}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-\cos(n)}{n^2}f(t)\cos(t).$$ (Integration working omitted.) Does that count as calculating the Fourier series, or do I need to do anything more?

---

**Update:** Second attempt.

$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{8}{\pi^2}\sum_{p=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2p-1)^2}\cos\left((2p-1)\frac{2\pi}{4}t\right)+\frac{2}{(4p-2)^2}\cos\left((4p-2)\frac{2\pi}{4}t\right).$$

Comment: The whole point is to represent $f$ (in some way) by the sum of multiples of $\cos( n{2 \pi \over 4} t)$. So the $f(t) \cos t$ is not correct.

Comment: @copper.hat OK, got it. Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully did not mislead earlier, but the coefficients are not correct either. But the big idea comes first :-).

Comment: @copper.hat Agreed. I've updated the OP with another attempt. Does it look any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I have no made any mistakes, there are a few errors in your formula.

I would be more explicit about the steps involved as it makes it easier to see where mistakes are made later.

The first term should be the average, which you can see graphically to be ${1 \over 4}$.

The remaining terms are given by
$A_n = {2 \over T} \int_0^T f(t) \cos ( n {2 \pi \over T}) dt$ where $f$ is $T$ periodic.

$A_n = {1 \over 2} \int_{-1}^1 (1-|t|) \cos ( n {  \pi \over 2} t) dt = \int_0^1(1-t) \cos ( n {  \pi \over 2} t) dt = {1 - \cos (n {\pi \over 2}) \over n ({ \pi \over 2})^2 } = {4 \over \pi^2}{1 - \cos (n {\pi \over 2}) \over n  }$.

Note that for $n=1,2,3,4,...$ we have $1 - \cos (n {\pi \over 2}) = 1,2,1,0,...$, and so

\begin{eqnarray}
f(t) &=& {1 \over 4} + {4 \over \pi^2}(\sum_{p=1}^\infty (\text{terms with }n=2p-1) + \\
&\ \ \ \ \ & 2\sum_{p=1}^\infty (\text{terms with }n=4p-2) ),
\end{eqnarray}

which gives

$f(t) = {1 \over 4} + {4 \over \pi^2}\sum_{p=1}^\infty ( {1 \over 2p-1}\cos ((2p-1) {\pi \over 2}t)+ {2 \over 4p-2}\cos ((4p-2) {\pi \over 2}t)$.